# How to use double void pointer effectively

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

Please let me know what I have done wrong.

I have two structures

```
struct a{
   few elements;
   void **ptr;
};

struct b {
   few elements;
};

I tried to allocate memory for these two structures like
func2(struct a *aptr)
{
   struct b *bptr = kmalloc(sizeof(struct b), GFP_KERNEL);
   aptr->ptr = (void *)&bptr;
   // here *(aptr->ptr) is pointing correctly to bptr.
}
func1()
{
   struct a *aptr = kmalloc(sizeof(struct a), GFP_KERNEL);
   func2(aptr);
   /*though aptr->ptr is pointing correctly, *(aptr->ptr) is no more pointing to bptr*/
}
```

I'm trying this way so that I can use `container_of` effectively.
Please correct me if my implementation is wrong.

Observation: If I declare `struct b *bptr` outside the function scope, `*(aptr->ptr)` is pointing correctly to bptr.

Comment: func1() is the main calling function. func1() and func2() may be in different files.

Comment: Why do you have a `void **` and not a `void *`?

Comment: If I use void *, I'm unable to use container_of to retain aptr's address.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
 aptr->ptr = (void *)&bptr;
```

you assign the **address of a local variable**, which goes out of scope when the function returns. Did you perhaps mean to assign `bptr` instead of `&bptr`?

Comment: @narain almost certainly you do not want to assign &bptr to anywhere.   You don't care where the pointer is stored! you care about the pointer to the block of memory you allocated.   Just assign `aptr->ptr = kmalloc(...)`

Comment: I don't know how much to allocate. struct b can be in some other file.

Comment: Not knowing how much to allocate is not a problem you're going to solve by remembering the address of an automatic variable after exiting a function call.

Comment: If I use aptr->ptr = kmalloc(...), will I be able to retain aptr address using aptr->ptr and container_of  ?

Comment: @Narain Yes, `aptr->ptr` will hold its value, since it has allocated storage duration, i.e. it lives until you `kfree(aptr)`.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the address of a local automatic variable and saving it away is wrong.   You're remembering some address on the stack!

```
func2(struct a *aptr)
{
    struct b *bptr = kmalloc(sizeof(struct b), GFP_KERNEL);
    aptr->ptr = (void *)&bptr;
   // here *(aptr->ptr) is pointing to bptr, which is only on the stack
   // until you exit the block, then it ceases to exist and you're pointing
   // to some unknown/invalid data.
}
```

Comment: Yeah I got that point. but how to resolve it. I dont want it (struct b *bptr) to declare global.